# What's the difference between `nfs-server` and `nfs-kernel-server`?

Tags: systemd, nfs

Autocompletion shows

```
$ sudo service nfs- stop
nfs-blkmap         nfs-common         nfs-config         nfs-idmapd         nfs-kernel-server  nfs-mountd         nfs-server         nfs-utils
```

What's the difference between `nfs-server` and `nfs-kernel-server`? Do I need to start both and stop both like

```
$ sudo service nfs-server start

$ sudo service nfs-kernel-server start

$ sudo service nfs-server stop

$ sudo service nfs-kernel-server stop
```

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? That information might be relevant here...

Comment: lubuntu 18.04. @filbranden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is their name; `nfs-kernel-server` is an alias for `nfs-server`:

```
$ systemctl show -pNames nfs-server
Names=nfs-server.service nfs-kernel-server.service
```

Starting and stopping either one will start and stop the NFS server.

Comment: `aptitude show nfs-server` is informative.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP but strictly speaking it informs about packages, not services. One needn’t try to install the `nfs-server` package to get the `nfs-server` service; it’s installed by the `nfs-kernel-server` package. (Put another way, Tim’s question about services remains, regardless of the package setup.) Amusingly, the package setup is the opposite of the service setup: the `nfs-kernel-server` package provides the `nfs-server` virtual package, but it’s the `nfs-server` service which is aliased as `nfs-kernel-server`.